# How to validate against a set of rules/functions

Tags: c#, validation, delegates, func

How would I go best about validating an object by a set of rules each with an ID and a result type that has to be returned.

I would like something like a collection of Func's to which I would send the object while getting seperate results from each one of them. Is there some best practice around?

Comment: Sounds like you want a test class.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx

Comment: Not really. I do not need to test my own functionality but rather data at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little broad, but here's something I put together quickly to give you an idea:

```
public class ObjectValidator<T> where T : class 
{
    private List<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> m_rules = new List<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>();
    private List<ValidationResult> m_results = new List<ValidationResult>();

    public ObjectValidator<T> AddRule(Expression<Func<T, bool>> rule)
    {
        // Null check, blah blah
        m_rules.Add(rule);
        return this; // Allows for chaining multiple rules together.
    }

    public List<ValidationResult> Validate(T objectInstance)
    {
        foreach (var rule in m_rules)
        {
            var isValid = rule.Compile()(objectInstance);

            var fieldExpression = rule.Body as BinaryExpression;
            var fieldNameExpression = fieldExpression.Left as MemberExpression;
            string fieldName = fieldNameExpression != null ? fieldNameExpression.Member.Name : "Object";

            var result = new ValidationResult(isValid, fieldName);
            m_results.Add(result);
        }

        return m_results;
    }
}
```

Here we have a generic class called `ObjectValidator` that has two methods: `AddRule()` which allows you to pass in an Expression of type `Func<T, bool>` which is essentially your validation condition. The only reason we're passing in an `Expression` instead of a plain `Func` is so that we can capture the actual property name as part of the validation result.

The `Validate` method will then take in an instance of the object you're validating and runs each rule against it, putting the results in a list of this type:

```
public class ValidationResult
{
    public ValidationResult()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public ValidationResult(bool isValid, string fieldName)
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        IsValid = isValid;
        FieldName = fieldName;
    }

    public Guid ID { get; private set; }

    public bool IsValid { get; set; }

    public string FieldName { get; set; }
}
```

And then finally to use it, let's say we have an object called `Test` that we'd like to validate, which looks like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }

    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use the validator like this:

```
Test instance = new Test { Property1 = 5, Property2 = "Bar" };

ObjectValidator<Test> validator = new ObjectValidator<Test>();
var results = validator.AddRule(x => x.Property1 < 10)
    .AddRule(x => x.Property2 == "Foo")
    .Validate(instance);
```

Run it to see how it looks :) you'll obviously need to make changes to match your requirements, but it's something to get you started.